# Implement Bitwise OR instead of multiple In clause in sql query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a query which uses `IN` clause (can use `EXISTS` also) for multiple columns which are filtered using `OR` Clause inside `WHERE` Clause. Is there any better approach to write this query.

```
SELECT columndata FROM TABLE1
WHERE column1key in (select columnkey from #temptable1)
OR column2key in (select columnkey from #temptable2)
OR column3key IN (SELECT columnkey FROM #temptable3)
```

Comment: What do you consider a "better approach"? More performant (if so, next question is: Do you have performance issues)? More maintainable? Easier to read?

Comment: If you've written clear SQL that produces the correct result set, you don't generally tune it by changing its text (because any logically equivalent query *should* generate approximately the same execution plan). You tune it by analyzing the execution plan and identifying missing indexes.

Comment: There could be 1 to 9 such columns in where clause. TABLE has 3000000+ rows in table. So i was just thinking if i could active bitwise or in this scenario. The above query is part of dynamic sql. Query takes around 3~15 sec for execution. Hence was thinking tweak this component to get faster results.

Comment: @MayurPatil I would look at indexes first. OR is still OR; whether bitwise or not. For example, are there suitable indexes on columnkey in #temptableX?

Comment: No the table does not have indexes on those columns. Table has in total 49 columns out of which 30 tables are candidate columns for filtering data. Clustered index is on primarykey and there is an index on date column to filter using date.

Comment: @MayurPatil indexes on the temptable will help here at least. On the main table, it will be probably be pointless because of OR

Answer (score 0):

You can go for 'LEFT JOIN' as shown below

```
    SELECT columndata 
    FROM TABLE1 tab1
    LEFT JOIN #temptable1  t1 on tab1.column1key =  t1.columnkey
    LEFT JOIN #temptable2  t2 on tab1.column2key =  t2.columnkey
    LEFT JOIN #temptable3  t3 on tab1.column3key =  t3.columnkey
```

Comment: but be aware that this may multiply up the number of result columns for a) if there are multiple matching entries in the temp tables and b) if the temp tables are unrelated and we produce effectively a Cartesian join between them.

Comment: Also you have to add `WHERE` clause. `WHERE t1.columnkey IS NOT NULL OR ...`.

Comment: temptables will always have unique records. But the doubt here i have is why would left join perform better than IN clause. I am not able to understand this part is such scenarios. could you please put some light on this @sahi

Comment: Also the table TABLE1 has 3000000+ rows. so performance is major factor in this scenario

Comment: Subquery in Where Clause impact Performace

Comment: @Sahi no it does not. EXISTS and IN generate semi-join plans. LEFT JOIN generates equi-join plans. So you multiply rows and make performance worse.

Answer (score 0):

You may get better performance by this, which breaks down the SELECT into separate queries with a de-duplication later.

```
SELECT columndata FROM TABLE1
WHERE column1key in (select columnkey from #temptable1)
UNION
SELECT columndata FROM TABLE1
WHERE column2key in (select columnkey from #temptable2)
UNION
SELECT columndata FROM TABLE1
WHERE column3key IN (SELECT columnkey FROM #temptable3)
```

But you would really have to try it

With no or bad indexes, you still have to *scan* then same amount of data. With good indexes, this may work better...

As a side note, EXISTS and IN will give the same plan here

Comment: will try this if it improves performance with certain filter combinations